# Rails jQuery with Ajax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery

I'm a rails newbie and I cant seem to get jquery with ajax to work. I have installed the jquery-rails and done `rails g jquery:install`. Then I did a sample test by calling an alert in the application.js file and it worked. Then I created a controller action 'index' and made a link to it on one of my other pages. I thought to get ajax to work with it, I would simply create a index.js.erb file. However I then got an error saying template missing, so in my controllers' index action, I put the following code:

```
respond_to do |format|
 format.html
 format.js
end
```

However, I am not getting anything displayed on my page. In my index.js.erb file I have a simple alert message to test out if its working, and I cannot get that to even come up. Any suggestions? I don't know if it matters but I am using rails 3.0.7. Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery) will help you understand how to use jQuery in Rails Application:

Comment: Another [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript) to look at Unobtrusive Javascript in Rails 3

Answer (score 1):

RJS files didn't work with jQuery Plugin, so, you have to use `*.js.erb` extension in order to use javascript template, and these files are a kind of erb + javascript combination (like `*html.erb` files).

Answer (score -1):

Just wrote this using rails 3.0.7, jquery plugin should be compatible with rjs syntax

routes.rb

```
  get "main/index"
  get "main/hello"
```

main_controller.br

```
class MainController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def hello
  end

end
```

hello.js.rjs

```
page.alert("test");
```

index.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'test', main_hello_path, :remote => true %>
```